# Noun form of realistic?

Tags: nouns

I am looking for the noun form of the word *realistic*, or a word that would be equivalent. Something like "realisticity"? Here is the context:

> The (realisticity?) of the characters in a novel.

Comment: "Realism", perhaps?

Comment: I posted an answer here (*accuracy*, now deleted) but realised that it's not really applicable. A  fictional character is presumably not being compared to an actual person. Given the context, I feel the question is more about the characters' *believability*. I'd either choose that word, or *credibility*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realism is the noun for it.
Reference : http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/realism

Answer (score 1):

I would go for *Lifelikeness* as **Lifelike** is defined in [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lifelikeness):

> accurately representing or imitating real life